# Same symbology and color for all attributes of layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, visualisation

In QGIS 3.22.0 (Bialowieza) I have a polygon layer with different attributes.

I'm making a categorized map for each attribute in my table. For that I'm duplicating and renaming my layer corresponding to the attributes I want displayed. All attributes always have the values 0,1,2 or 3. The layers mostly have 2-3 values, but sometimes all 4.

I would like the value to correspond to the same color in each cateogrized map. I thought if I saved the style of the classification I could load it, when I want to display the next attribute. Unfortunately, when I save a style, it saves the value of the attribute with it. Meaning, that when I move on to the next value and load the style, it jumps back to my previous value.

Is there a possibility to save the style and use it for each value?

In the first Image you see my layer with 9 different attributes
[image]

For each attribute I would like to create its own map
[image]

Since all layers have the values 1,2,3 or 0, I would like all symbols to have the same color through out the 9 maps. Unfortunately I have to manually classify and change the colors of the symbols for every attribute
[image]

Comment: Sorry, question is unclear to me. Can you add more information and a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks Babel for your comment. I have to tried to be more specific, I hope you can help.

Comment: Just create a color ramp that fit your need, cause your attribute are always 0, 1, 2 or 3! And then create different style for each attribute… no need to duplicate your layer!

Comment: But I need to have a seperate map for each attribute. Thats why i have duplicated according to my attributes. What do you mean exactly with creating a color ramp that fits my needs, I dont seem to follow, sorry.

Comment: Would the following work for you instead? 1. Configure the symbology in your original layer. 2. Duplicate the layer. 3. Change the symbology in the duplicated layer to use the next attribute (this does not require a re-classification). 4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for each remaining attribute. This requires significantly fewer clicks than copy/pasting the symbology.

Comment: Hi Jake! I had originally configured the symbology before duplicating the layer. It requires less clicks, however, if i decide to change to colors/opacity of the symbol, I would need to  go back to each layer. I was wishing to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where the feature "Match to Saved Symbols" (and "Match to Symbols from File...") comes in handy.

To use this feature, you need to create styles in the Style Manager that have the same name as the attribute values you want to assign them to. In your case, you need styles called "0", "1", "2", and "3":

[image: "Style Manager"]

You can either create the required styles in the Style Manager, or you can save the styles from the Layer Styling panel:

[image: "Layer Styling" panel]

To apply these styles to your other layers, you select "Advanced"/"Match to Saved Symbols" in each layer's "Layer Styling" panel.

[image: "Layer styling" panel with "Advanced" dropdown opened]

If you want to change the style for one of the values later on, you edit the style in the Style Manager (not in the Layer Styling panel), and then re-run "Match to Saved Symbols" for each of your layers.

[image]

Comment: Perfect!!!! This was exactly what I was looking for. Excellent - this gets the job done. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you need to create a separate shapefile for each attribute. So your attribute table looks like the one below, several attributes all taking values within 0, 1, 2 and 3.

[image]

You need first to create a categorized symbology (`Properties -> Symbology -> Categorized`), use as a "Value" your first attribute ("att_1") and click "Classify" to import all four values (0, 1, 2, 3). That will give you the rendering below.

[image]

Then the only thing you need to do is to go back to your "Value" and select the next attribute from the dropdown menu (let's say "att_2") and just click "Apply" at the bottom and it will come up with the map below.

[image]

And then repeat the process for each attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. However, the reason I chose to duplicate the layer corresponding to the attributes is because 1) I can just "klick" in the Window with all the layers the map/attribute I need, without everytime going back to the symbology and changing the value. 2) Sometimes I need to display all the maps simultaneously (meaning, all the maps are visible and have a transparency of e.g.50%, and when all maps are "on", I can analyse the maps according how dark the colors become in different segments).